# how to prepare api using laravel and vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vue-component, infinite-loop

good day;
I am new in `vue.js` and I want to build API in my project `using vue.js and laravel`
I have some question and  answer because I got confused 
 I have services controller that return all service 
as below:-

```
class ServicesController extends Controller
{
    public function Services()
    {
        //get all serveice
        $services=Services::where(['deleted'=>1,'status'=>1])->get();
        return response()->json($services);
    }
}
```

and API route as below:-

```
Route::get('/Servicess', 'API\ServicesController@Services');
```

1. it is necessary to make a component to send a request to using
   `Axios` request to get data and if yes how to tell the mobile developer about a link to access it.
2. i want the steps from `vue.js` side to
   prepare data and send it using Axios

---

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: my problem is i did my project and work successfully as single page  and all request    using AXIOS  Request  but when i  go to make api  how can using axios and vue methodes that i created before to show data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use your  front-end javascript code inside php controllers, there are two ways to use the data; First: send it via the request. Second: fetch the required data at the back-end side and use it there.
Also there are many alternatives to Axios like the fetch api etc.

Update#1:
example controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function exampleMethod(Request $request){
    $name = $request->input('name');
    //DO sth 

    }

}
```

Route in api.php:

```
Route::get('/users', 'API\ExampleController@exampleMethod');
```

Comment: i m sorry could you give me example to understand you if available

Comment: Every request that you send via axios you can add data to that request, so the data is accessible in the laravel side.
you can also fetch the data that you wanted to send via xios request in the laravel side via minimum parameters that are required.

Comment: as mentioned above i can use java script data  that in include axios request   in side component how can is use axiox now?

Comment: For example send a post request and embed the data inside the request: `axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  });` sends a post request with two fields.

Comment: firsi i wnar to thank you for helping me  but i know this my quetion can i use axios request in side controller to get data

Comment: Yes! You can use axios to send request  to other controllers  too but before that you hva to define the endpoint in the routes `api.php` and specify your controller and method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211067/discussion-between-ahmed-gaber-and-eamirgh).